# ActiveAdmin has_many relation record doesnt save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

Im trying to save a post with category relation. 
These are my models

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizes
  has_many :post_categories, :through=>:categorizes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_categories
end

class PostCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizes
  has_many :posts, :through=>:categorizes
end

class Categorize < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :post_category
end
```

and in ActiveAdmin post.rb.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  permit_params :title, :content, post_category_ids:[:id]


  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :title
    column :post_category_id
    column :created_at

    actions
  end

  filter :created_at

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Post Details" do
      f.input :title
      f.input :content,:input_html => { :class => "tinymce_editor" }
      #f.input :post_categories, :as=> :check_boxes#, :collection => PostCategory.all

    end

    f.has_many :post_categories ,new_record: false do |c|
        c.inputs do
          c.input :title
        end
      end

    f.actions
  end

  controller do
      defaults :finder => :find_by_slug_url
  end

end
```

I need to see my all categories from post_categories and i should select more than one. 
i check in rails console but the post hasnt any category.

```
Post.First.post_categories equal to []
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `post_category_attributes` instead of `post_category_ids`

See more [here](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters).